# Is cppcheck aware of move semantics?

Tags: move-semantics, cppcheck

I'm writing a class that more or less looks like this

```
struct Foo {
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar_ptr;

    Foo(std::shared_ptr<Bar> b)
      : bar_ptr(std::move(b)) {}
};
```

and [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) warns

> (performance) Function parameter 'b' should be passed by reference.

I was under the impression that in this case `b` should *not* be any sort of reference. This would allow instances of `Foo` to optionally take complete control of the resource (the original shared pointer) vis-a-vis

```
auto bar1 = std::make_shared<Bar>(...);

Foo my_foo(bar1); // bar1 remains untouched
Foo your_foo(std::move(bar1)); // takes complete control of the bar1 
                               // resource; bar1 now invalid
```

Am I not using something correctly, or is this not something cppcheck is aware of yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck developer. It seems to me this is a false positive, Cppcheck should not warn. Probably we should not warn for std::shared_pointer parameters in any functions. I created this ticket: http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/8400

Comment: I had been searching for this answer for some time. I will suppress this check in my current code.

Comment: This should be the case for all objects passed by value and immediately moved from.